# How can I find the length of the third side of any triangle?

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry

I will know the length of two sides of any triangle that I use, but I will not know any of the angles (unless there is a fast way to figure this out in the field). The following is a link to an example of what I could be dealing with (not to scale and not an image because I'm new.....). http://imgur.com/aYGR2lM
Don't down vote my question because I don't completely know what I'm doing. That is why I asked in the first place. How could I find the angle where I am at in the field?

Comment: With the info given it is impossible to find out the unknown length

Comment: You need the angle between the two lines as well. see: [algebra/trig-solving-triangles](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-triangles.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the angle, you can't know the length of the third side.
Think about it, there's tons of triangle with two sides with the same length. You'll need more information - angle, area, something...